# SPA with REST API, how to approach undo action

Tags: rest, single-page-application, undo

Let's say I'd like to implement Google's undo send email feature in a SPA with a REST style API. Since we're working in a SPA, we can't add a simple time-out, since there is a possibility that the window will be closed.

How would you implement such functionality? Perhaps something like:

`POST /email/sendingQueue`

And to undo:

`DELETE /email/sendingQueue/{id}`

But that automatically means you need to create a queue. Is there a simpler/better/alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it, could be that being 'sent' is a property of the actual email. Like a `sentStatus` that could hold values such as `not-sent`, `queued` and `sent`.

This might be a viable approach if you don't like creating a separate queue resource.